# Requesting someone to give a speech

Tags: speech

I need to anchor a very formal event. However, I am having trouble with using different phrases in my speech. For example, when I want to call upon someone to deliver a presentation/ speech, I am at a loss of words. Can someone please help me find phrases similar to

> "I now request  Mr XYZ to deliver the welcome address."

Comment: Your question reads either too broad or primarily opinion-based. [What research have you done?](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=s45BVoWaOIrN8gf1lpygCA#q=synonym+give+speech)

Comment: I looked at synonyms of "request" and "deliver speech"...but none really suited the event. I need phrases saying "request to deliver the speech' in different ways.

Comment: This is simply too broad.  Is the person forewarned?  How formal is the meeting?  How formal (long-winded) is the norm for introductions?  There are many variations that might (or might not) be appropriate.

Comment: Note that for a great many and possibly most native speakers in North America, your sentence is not grammatical, because in these speakers *request* does **ɴᴏᴛ** behave exactly as *ask* behaves. These are all allowed: *“I ask Mr X to speak. I ask that Mr X speak. I request that Mr X speak.”* What you can’t do with *request* for us is request someone **ᴛᴏ** do something; it cannot take an infinitive the way *ask* can.

Answer (score 1):

The best I remember is to introduce the person to the audience and welcome him to give a speech.

- **Please join me in welcoming Mr.Andrew Simons, head of department.**
- **Let me now introduce Mr.Andrew Simons, head of department.**

Perhaps this will help a little:

- http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/to-perform-a-ceremony-or-to-give-a-speech